# Is it possible to map a type to a string constant?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I was wondering if we could get a type in scope from a string. My use case is the following:

```js
import type { User, Receiver, Driver, Bus } from '../utils/types';


type tables = 'users' | 'receivers' | 'drivers' | 'buses';
type resources = {
    [k in tables]: Capitalize<k>
}

/* the `resources` type becomes

type resources = {
    users: "Users";
    receivers: "Receivers";
    drivers: "Drivers";
    buses: "Buses";
}
*/
```

What I'd want to do is to map the string types of the keys of the `resource` type with the imported types.

The results would be:

```js
import type { User, Receiver, Driver, Bus } from '../utils/types';


type tables = 'users' | 'receivers' | 'drivers' | 'buses';

// a hypothetical generic is used here 
type resources = {
    [k in tables]: GetTypeFromString<Capitalize<k>>
}

/* the `resources` type would be
type resources = {
    users: Users;
    receivers: Receivers;
    drivers: Drivers;
    buses: Buses;
}*/

// instead of

/* type resources = {
    users: "Users";
    receivers: "Receivers";
    drivers: "Drivers";
    buses: "Buses";
}
*/
```

Comment: Have you tried enums in TS ?

Comment: This is not really possible. You would need a mapping between the string literal type names and the types itself. But that would defeat the purpose of this question...

Comment: @GouthamJ.M yes but I don't see how they help me with this problem.

Comment: @TobiasS. Exactly what I tried earlier but thought I could simplify more and avoid the additional boilerplate. Thank you for your insight.